# Can I use a custom style sheet (CSS) for user modifications?

Tags: theme, css

I have noticed that the content of CiviCRM pages contain selectors such as:

- Type selectors `elementname`,
- Class selectors `.classname`, and
- ID selectors `#idname`.

I know these can be used to modify the style rules to alter a specific element (or elements) of a page.

What stylesheet do you use to alter page content?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Usually I add a section to the theme's CSS rather than editing any core files in CiviCRM.

Note that there is also a "Custom CSS URL" that you can add, and you can also disable the core CiviCRM CSS if you want to. (**Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs**)

[image: Resource URLS]

Comment: Remember to use `https` if you are wanting to use the file on a secure connection, or the browser might ignore the custom css file--Ask me how I know.  :)

Comment: @Larya-CEDC.org could you please guide me.Thanks

Comment: @MdMaidulIslam Which part above is unclear?

Comment: @Laryn-CEDC.org How we can Use custom css in civicrm . step by step guide any blog/youtube link.

Comment: @MdMaidulIslam As stated above, you can override CSS in your CMS theme's CSS files, or create a custom CSS file and put the URL in the "Custom css URL" field shown above.