# how to extend a field view in the new contribution screen?

Tags: civicontribute, theme

Dear I need to extend the **view** of the Fund (Financial Type) field in the view of the new contribution? How can I do that? Please check the attached photo.
[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to avoid the name of long financial types from being cut off?

Comment: Looking down that list (and none of my business really) but I wonder if 'Financial Type' is the best way to create the differentiation that you are after. It could be a clever workaround to get you exactly what you need, but given I see 20 items between Soc... and Spe.... suggests you could have many hundreds in total, and hence i wonder if this approach scales that well.

Comment: I mostly agree with Pete - this is a LOT of financial types.  However, if you are using accounting integration, this may be exactly what you need.  I have a client with 1600 financial types because they must all have a unique general ledger code in their chart of accounts.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so much a CiviCRM question as a CSS question, which is answered [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411484/how-do-i-adjust-the-width-of-a-dropdown-select-box).

There are several ways to edit CSS, depending on your CMS.  Some WordPress themes allow you to edit it directly from the WP dashboard.  You can always edit your Drupal or WP theme's CSS, and you can specify a [custom CiviCRM CSS file](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/can-i-use-a-custom-style-sheet-css-for-user-modifications).

It looks like the CSS you want is:

```
.crm-contribution-form-block-financial_type_id #financial_type_id {
    width: 400px;
}
```

You can also experiment with:

```
#financial_type_id {
    width: 400px;
}
```

The second option should change the width in more locations.

Comment: Dear Jon,   Since I am new to the Civicrm, we are using WordPress for Civicrm. How can I reach/edit the CSS of this page/theme in wordpress?

Comment: @FrancisSleibi I don't think I can easily walk you through all the steps without knowing what you are able to do.  Do you have a way of putting files on the server?  Either with FTP or a file manager or something else?

Comment: I need to access the CSS file which is related to "financial_type_id" to extend the display of it. How can I edit this file?

Comment: @FrancisSleibi The easiest thing to do is to create a new CSS file.  Do you have a way of putting files on your server?  Are you the person responsible for the installation and maintenance of CiviCRM?  This is a more technical task.

Comment: Our IT administrator is not available and I am trying to solve this problem and since I am new on CiviCRM , I could not manage to solve it. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: To make things more clear, the display of Fund (Financial Type) field such as the above photo  with field data  of "Sons and Daughters of Joseph and Regina Abu Zarur in memory of F"  are not shown completely. How can I show/display it completely?

Comment: @FrancisSleibi I've asked twice if you have a way of putting a file on the server, but you haven't responded.  This is unfortunately a technical task, and it may be best to wait for your IT administrator to be available.